# How to reset the value on the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the first click the value has been selected, but I need to reset the value when we click for the second time.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="CreditPoint" class="reqValidation col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 170px; ">Credit</label>
```

Comment: please share some codes and explanation

Comment: Do you have some javascript code?

Comment: It's better if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32880147/edit) your question to put the code in.

Comment: anybody found the answer please let me know..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label id="reset" for="CreditPoint" class="reqValidation col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 170px;">Credit</label>
<label for="dummy" class="col-lg-1 control-label" style="width: 5px; "></label>
<div class="creditpoint creditpoint-2" class="form-control col-lg-4" style="width: 500px; ">
    <a href="#" class="creditpoint-1" alt="1" data-val="1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="creditpoint-2" alt="2" data-val="2"></a>
    <a href="#" class="creditpoint-3" alt="3" data-val="3"></a>
    <p class="creditpoint-label">Not Rated</p>
    <label style="width: 170px; ">1 Star - Good, 2 Star - Very Good, 3 Star -Excellent</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".creditpoint a").click (function (e){
        var rate = $(this).data("val");
        var cRate = $(".creditpoint-label").data ("rate");
        if (rate == cRate){
            rate = 0;
        }
        $(".creditpoint-label").data ("rate", rate);
        if (rate>0){
            $(".creditpoint-label").html (rate + " Star")
        }else{
            $(".creditpoint-label").html ("Not Rated")
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

css

```
.creditpoint-label {
    width:100%;
    clear:both;   
}
.creditpoint a {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;
}
```

jsfiddle

[Js Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2vdbsj9z/1/)

Comment: Hi Chandrashekhar please confirm what exactly you are trying to achive.the above solution will show the rate inside the p tag and once you clicked the same star again it will become not rated.